# oracle create table into new database with primary key and indexes

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called TableA in DatabaseA and I want to create the same TableA in DatabaseB.  I am able to do so but copying only the structure and the data, I seem unable to also create the primary keys and indexes.  Is there an SQL statement I can use that copies the table structure, the table data, the primary keys and indexes please?

I am using Oracle 11G.

Comment: Use exp/inp utilities. Follow this link: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm  and also this one: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ

Comment: What interface do you use to interact with the database? SQL*Plus? SQL Developer? Toad? Something else? Each has its own export capabilities. For example, if you use SQL Developer, you can right-click a table, select Export, select a few settings and you get all the DDL (including PK and indexes) and DML (inserts to reproduce the data), all in one script.

Comment: I was using Benthic, but downloaded SQL Developer and followed your suggestion ... all good! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. First Method**

To get tables and indexes without data see following post
[Stack Post](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm)

after creating table you can load data using

```
insert into dest_table as select * from source_table
```

**2. Second Method**

use expdp to take backup of source table using `table=yourtable` parameter as this will by default will take indexes and when you will import using impdp on destination database it will automatically rebuild those indexes.